# Azure CosmosDB and a single Singleton for Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, singleton, azure-cosmosdb

Theory:
So in my attempt to always improve i came across this conundrum. The following code underneath is the existing code. My understanding is that the app will actually make a separate connection for each of the following singletons. Since these all point at the same instance I am fairly certain that if you hit an index that has 2 of those classes youre usage of cosmos DB will be greater.

Question: Can you reduce the following singleton declarations to use a generic object of T so that way you can use one singleton vs the N+1?

```
        services.AddSingleton<IDocumentDBRepository<Car>>(new DocumentDBRepository<Car>("Database"));
        services.AddSingleton<IDocumentDBRepository<House>>(new DocumentDBRepository<House>("Database"));
        services.AddSingleton<IDocumentDBRepository<Employer>>(new DocumentDBRepository<Employer>("Database"));
        services.AddSingleton<IDocumentDBRepository<Photo>>(new DocumentDBRepository<Photo>("Database"));
```

Also if you have an alternate suggestion for me or something else to even look into please advise so i can research into it also!

Comment: Does the DocumentDBRepository class creates it's own Cosmos DB Client?

Comment: Is your question related to reducing Cosmos DB usage or reducing lines of code for service registration in DI container?

Comment: (A) it does not create its own client.
(B) its mainly reducing lines of code as well as reducing usage; however, the usage problem has been solved in a way and i will try to now leverage caching to answer that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may change your `DocumentDBRepository` class to directly accept a `DocumentClient`. In this way, it will not create a new client but use the specified one.

However, I do not think you should do this. Because, the CosmosDB usage count is based on RU not connection. Link for [CosmosDB pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/)

> Azure Cosmos DB bills for provisioned throughput and consumed storage
>   by the hour.
>
> Provisioned throughput is expressed in Request Units per second
>   (RU/s), which can be used for various database operations (e.g.,
>   inserts, reads, replaces, upserts, deletes, queries, etc.). For
>   example, 1 RU/s is sufficient for processing one eventually consistent
>   read per second of 1K item, and 5 RU/s is sufficient for processing
>   one write per second of 1K item.
>
> Storage is billed for each GB used for your SSD-backed data and index.

Comment: I actually had forgotten all about RUs and it only being based on usage and for some reason in my mind i was picturing that when the object was instantiated that it was actually using the DB. So yea your spot on and thank you! I guess now it would just be to reduce code

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have several questions:

A) Your *Cosmos usage* only depends on the calls you make to the database and does not depend on how many services you create to access the database.

B) By looking at your code it seems that you are using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. This framework has support for open generics which in theory could reduce your four singleton registrations to a single registration using an open generic type. Something like:

```
.AddSingleton(typeof(IDocumentDBRepository<>), typeof(DocumentDBRepository<>)
```

Here the open generic service type is `IDocumentDBRepository<>` and the implementation type is `DocumentDBRepository<>`. When the dependency injection framework has to create an `IDocumentDBRepository<Car>` service it will create an `DocumentDBRepository<Car>` instance. This means that there will still be a repository instance for each specific document type (`Car`, `House` etc.) but you don't have to inject a service for each specific type.

Unfortunately, that is not possible in your case as you are using the constructor that require an argument for each of the four services. However, you might be able to refactor your services to work around this problem. One (general) solution is to introduce a factory:

```
public interface IDocumentDBRepositoryFactory<T>
{
    IDocumentDBRepository<T> Create(string databaseName);
}
```

And the implemenentation:

```
internal class DocumentDBRepositoryFactory<T>
{
    public IDocumentDBRepository<T> Create(string databaseName)
        => return new DocumentDBRepository(databaseName);
}
```

You then register this factory (using open generics):

```
.AddSingleton(typeof(IDocumentDBRepositoryFactory<>), typeof(DocumentDBRepositoryFactory<>)
```

Now the consumers of repositories will have to use an `IDocumentDBRepositoryFactory<T>` instance and call the `Create` method and supply the database name to get the actual `IDocumentDBRepository<T>` instance. Another option is to get rid of the `databaseName` argument to the factory method and instead configure the factory instance to supply this (presumably from configuration).

Introducing a factory allows you to postpone decisions from when you configure the system to when the system executes. In this case the decision about which database to connect to.

Comment: I will have to give this a try. Especially since I am in the process of refactoring a lot of my work to implement interfaces.

Also totally didn't dawn on me the pricing structure as described in my comment to Jack Lia below.